# Build features from update sites?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I'm building my own feature I can only include features and plugins that I have already installed in my current Eclipse installation. Is there no way to add features/plugins from an update site instead?

Or just point to a jar file on my desktop and say that this should be included?

This leads to a problem where I want to include a plugin version 1.0, but there is a later version of the same plugin that my system has loaded. So when I try to add the plugin I can only see the latest version, since that is what my system has loaded.

Comment: During PDE build or while exporting from your workspace?

Comment: PDE build non-headless using the export wizard from the feature editor within Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit your Target Platform at `Preferences>Plug-in Development>Target Platform`

[image: Target Platform Preference Page]

You can create a new target platform based off of your currently running instance, and then include the extra update sites or local directories to pull in the other plugins.

When using PDE build, you use `p2.mirror` and `p2.repo2Runnable` to create the same kind of target platform.